# PMD rule to detect a call to a method

Tags: java, pmd, rule

I'd like to create a rule to detect calls to a method named "method" of class "Task". Sounds basic but can't find how to do it.

Did:

```
public class CustomRule extends AbstractJavaRule {
    public Object visit(ASTVariableDeclaratorId node, Object data) {
        if (!TypeHelper.isA(node.getNameDeclaration(), Task.class)) {
            return data;
        }

        for (NameOccurrence occ : node.getUsages()) {
            NameOccurrence qualifier = occ.getNameForWhichThisIsAQualifier();
            if (qualifier != null) {
                if (qualifier.getImage().equals("method")) {
                    addViolation(data, occ.getLocation());
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

This works for

```
Task t = new Task(); 
t.method();
```

but not for

```
context.getTask().method();
```

Comment: I think the issue here is that we do not know the type that context.getTask() returns (we know it's a Task, but PMD does not), so it does not know that you are calling the method() method on a instance of Task, or something else. This requires looking at several classes, including "context", to see what getTask is returning, so it may not be possible with PMD.

I'm having the same issue.